# How do I run my application on my iOS 10.1 Beta Device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10

I updated to the iOS 10.1 beta on my device and Xcode 8 will not let me run the application on my device. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: No version of Xcode lets you run a simulator on a real iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to build and run your application onto your iOS 10.1 Beta device, you need to install the latest beta build of Xcode. The latest build is [Xcode 8.1 Beta 3](https://developer.apple.com/download/).

> Xcode 8.1 beta 3 includes SDKs for iOS 10.0 and it's latest beta build, watchOS 3.0, macOS 10.12, and tvOS 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `Xcode 8.1 beta 3`

https://developer.apple.com/download/

`Includes the SDKs for iOS 10.1 beta, macOS 10.12.1 beta, watchOS 3.1 beta, and tvOS 10.0.1 beta. 
Xcode 8.1 beta requires OS X 10.11.5 or later.`